# How to track session without spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

So, I am working on creating a simple chat app. I'm not using spring security.

So, in front end, the user enters their name which is handled by this controller.

```
@PostMapping("/addUser")
public User addUser(@RequestBody String name, HttpServletRequest request) {         
    String session = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("sessionId");
    System.out.println("Session id is " + session);
    User newUser = new User(name, session);
    userService.addUser(newUser);
    System.out.println(newUser);
                    
    return newUser;
}
```

I'm using pre handler method handler interceptor to generate session id for the user. Below is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Its working");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = servletRequest.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("sessionId", session.getId());
                        
        System.out.println("Connected with session id : " + session.getAttribute("sessionId"));
    }
    return true;
}
```

So, I want to make sure that whenever users are inactive for cetain time, I want to end the session for that user and also remove that user from the arraylist of user where I have kept all the users who register by entering their name (in the front end).

Is it possible to achieve without sprin security or do I have to learn spring security to implement it.

I did try using task scheduler but then I found out in some article that its impossible to call HttpSession there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the session life (time it can be inactive before being killed) with `server.servlet.session.timeout=30m`

You can take the user out of your list by implementing a `HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed` - [spring-boot-session-listener](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-session-listener/)

Comment: it worked, I had to use '@Component' instead of '@WebListner'. Thanks for the solution but now I'm facing a new one can you help me with it?? below contains the details of the question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75350217/session-destroyed-method-of-httpsessionlistner

Answer (score 0):

if you use WebSocket, You can use heartbeat for your session, on the other hand, if you use rest then you should keep the session in memory(redis, hazelcast, or in-memory (singleton object) like map<key, session>,
(keep in mind, the client should send a disconnect request or you should control it in the backend)

Comment: Do you have an article that can assist me using both? I'm using websocket too but currently I'm trying to achieve my goal using just rest later on I will shift to websocket.

Comment: You can use spring web socket support which has a lot of things about this https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html btw maybe there have a misunderstood you need to always keep the session in memory (if the client is connected you need to put to the memory)