# Session Destroyed method of HttpSessionListner

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

So, I'm using HttpSessionListner and based what I found, there it said that using

`server.servlet.session.timeout=1m`

will disconned the inactive session i.e. invalading the session by calling sessionDestroyed method of the class implmenting HttpSessionListner.

The good part is that, yeah its working like it should be but the problem is, after 1 minute (which I set 1 minute because that's the miniumum requirement for tomcat) every session get destroyed no matter whether the session makes any requests to the server or not.

Is that how session timeout is suppose to work or I'm doing it in worng way.

Here is my code from the class implementing HttpSessionListner

```
@Component
public class SessionListner implements HttpSessionListener {

    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionListner.class);

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpSession session = se.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("sessionId", session.getId());
        log.info(session.getId());
        System.out.println(this.userService.getUser().size());
        
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpSession httpSession = se.getSession();

        if(userService.getUser().size() >0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.userService.getUser().size(); i++) {
                if (this.userService.getUser().get(i).getSessionId().equals(httpSession.getId())) {
                    this.userService.getUser().remove(this.userService.getUser().get(i));
                }
            }
            }
        httpSession.invalidate();
        log.info("Destroying session");
    }
}
```

I tried making changes in the frontend in a way I can make request to the server but well no matter how much I make request, the session get destroyed after assigned timeout time.

Comment: It could be due to the session actually not being accessed. Try this, create a servlet and access a session repeatedly, getAttribute/setAttribute and check the behaviour

Comment: That’s the right config. How do you know all sessions are invalidated? How are you touching the sessions so the stay alive? Add this to the question. I suggest to increase the life to 180s while you debug. BTW: httpSession.invalidate(); should not be in the sessionDestroyed()

Comment: @JohnWilliams, so, there will always be communication between server and client because I have make sure in frontend that the client will be sending a message to the server every second to check if new user is available there meaning that the only time there won't be commucation is when either client closes the site.

Comment: How do you know all sessions are invalidated?

Comment: because using front end, I'm creating 2 sessions, and in eclipse console, after a minute there are 2 session destroyed method printing on console and since in my code, once the session get destroyed, I'm removing that user from the array list of users meaning that both user just disappears from the list.

Comment: How are you touching the sessions so they stay alive?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I finally find out what the problem is. So, what was happening is that when frontend makes a request to the server, new session was created for each request meaning that even if the browswer was open and making continuous requests to the server, the request was being made through a new session id rather than the one that was first created by sessionCreated method resulting in httpsessionlistner thinking that the session is inactive

Don't have the solution yet but the problem that I'm asking is solved.